# Using QT Unit Tests in a project - conflicting main(...) functions

Tags: c++, unit-testing, qt, qt-creator

I set my first steps upon the noble path of  using unit tests to develop my application, but it proves to be a steep and rough one. I'm developing an application in Qt, so thought to reach for their QTestLib framework. Now, I understand how to make unit tests, but I can't seem to figure out how to incorporate unit testing into a project. 
Say I have a console application which just has a main.cpp and a cpp and h file for a class I want to develop, say MyClass. I guess the right thing to do would be to create a corresponding test class MyClassTest with its h and cpp files. But should I put it into the same project? Or rather create a separate project just for unit tests that will have access to files in "main" project (not sure how would I do that yet)?

And if both main application and the test are in the same project, how do I run tests without running the application or the other way round? I tried incorporating files from Qt's Tutorial 1 on unit testing into a console project, but the problem with it is that they use a macro `QTEST_MAIN(TestQString)` which expands into a `main(...)` function. This causes conflicts with the `main(...)` in the main.cpp. Well, I can rename either one, but the problem still stands - how do I then run either the tests or the application itself? If I override `QTEST_MAIN` macro (which is a bad idea anyway) I disable the tests. If I rename `main(...)` function in the main.cpp, then the actual application never gets executed. I guess there should be a way to make two separate executables for the project, one running unit tests, and another launching the application, but can't figure out how to go about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Definitely create a separate project for your tests. If you arrange the application project and  test project in side-by-side directories, you should be able to reference your code units from your application project using relative paths in your `test.pro` file.

I use the very handy test runner presented on [this blog](http://qtcreator.blogspot.ca/2010/04/sample-multiple-unit-test-project.html).

Comment: I just stumbled upon that article a few minutes ago, indeed seems like the way to go - thanks!