# Qt: How to organize Unit Test with more than one class?

Tags: unit-testing, qt4, qt-creator

I have a Qt Unit test (sub)project, which generates me one class (with the main generated by `QTEST_APPLESS_MAIN`).I can start this from within Qt Creator as console app.

Q: How would I add additional classes as test cases to this particular project.

1. If these classes only have "test" slots (`private Q_SLOTS`), the methods are not called, but just the ones of the class with `QTEST_APPLESS_MAIN`
2. Since there can be only one `main(..)`, I cannot use `QTEST_APPLESS_MAIN` with more than one class in the project (is that correct?)
3. Of course, I can manually "wire" the slots in the (additional) classes with the one class containing the `main`, but this is very tedious.

So what is the best way to run unit test over several classes in a unit test project?

PS:
In " [Using QT Unit Tests in a project - conflicting main(...) functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780602/using-qt-unit-tests-in-a-project-conflicting-main-functions) " a [Blog is mentioned](http://qtcreator.blogspot.ca/2010/04/sample-multiple-unit-test-project.html), however, I cannot download the zip describing the solution.

[image: Qt Unit Test subproject]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As per the solution you linked to, the way to accomplish testing two (or more) classes within a single Qt unit test project is to ensure that each class to be tested has a corresponding test class, and that you've created a custom `int main` that executes each test class.

For example:

```
class TestClassA : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   TestClassA();

   ...

private Q_SLOTS:
   void testCase1();
   ...
};

class TestClassB : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   TestClassB();

   ...

private Q_SLOTS:
   void testCase2();
   ...
};

void TestClassA::testCase1()
{
   // Define test here.
}

void TestClassB::testCase2()
{
   // Define test here.
}

// Additional tests defined here.

// Note: This is equivalent to QTEST_APPLESS_MAIN for multiple test classes.
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int status = 0;
   {
      TestClassA tc;
      status |= QTest::qExec(&tc, argc, argv);
   }
   {
      TestClassB tc;
      status |= QTest::qExec(&tc, argc, argv);
   }
   return status;
}
```

Obviously, the different test classes can be spread out over multiple translation units, then simply included in the translation unit with your `int main`.  Don't forget to include the appropriate `.moc` files.

Comment: Straight forward, should have looked at the QTEST_APPLESS_MAIN DEFINE sooner.

Comment: I just noticed you are the one who answered this question, who also commented on my other question earlier, so i suspect you are in a good position to explain the difference.

Comment: You don't need to include a .moc if you have 2 separate files for your test (.cpp and .h).

Comment: I wouldn't like working in a project set up like that. It breaks passing a method name on the command line, to debug a failing test without first going through all other test methods.

Answer (score 21):

Based in the accepted answer and if you are using C++11 you could be interested in a solution using lambdas. It avoids you write the same code everytime. Although you can replace the lambda with a function, I think a lambda is cleaner.

```
#include <QtTest>

#include "test1.h"
#include "test2.h"


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int status = 0;
   auto ASSERT_TEST = [&status, argc, argv](QObject* obj) {
     status |= QTest::qExec(obj, argc, argv);
     delete obj;
   };

   ASSERT_TEST(new Test1());
   ASSERT_TEST(new Test2());

   return status;
}

#ifndef TEST1_H
#define TEST1_H
```

Sample test

```
#include <QtTest>

class Test1 : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

  private Q_SLOTS:
    void testCase1();
};
```

Comment: What is the reason for creating the objects dynamically? You could also pass a reference, then you don't have to handle object destruction.     `auto ASSERT_TEST = [&status, argc, argv](QObject &obj) {
        status |= QTest::qExec(&obj, argc, argv);
    };
    ASSERT_TEST(Test1());`

Comment: @ChristopheWeis I just prefer to use pointer when using `QObjects` to be sure to not mess with their lifetime in event loops, in that case a `obj->deleteLater()` would be better than a `delete obj`. But I think there is nothing wrong with your suggestion, it should work too

Comment: With the methods suggested, the QtCreator GUI is not able to integrate with the tests. Apparently QtCreator needs `QTEST_MAIN` to do so.

Answer (score 9):

Searching for this same answer, I found a very good solution from http://qtcreator.blogspot.de/2009/10/running-multiple-unit-tests.html. He creates a namespace with a container that registers all the tests created (via the DECLARE_TEST macro), and then uses it to run all the tests on the list.  I rewrote it to fit my code and I post my version here (My Qt Creator version: 4.1.0):

```
/* BASED ON
 * http://qtcreator.blogspot.de/2009/10/running-multiple-unit-tests.html
 */    
#ifndef TESTCOLLECTOR_H
#define TESTCOLLECTOR_H

#include <QtTest>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <string>

namespace TestCollector{
typedef std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<QObject> > TestList;
inline TestList& GetTestList()
{
   static TestList list;
   return list;
}

inline int RunAllTests(int argc, char **argv) {
    int result = 0;
    for (const auto&i:GetTestList()) {
        result += QTest::qExec(i.second.get(), argc, argv);
    }
    return result;
}

template <class T>
class UnitTestClass {
public:
    UnitTestClass(const std::string& pTestName) {
        auto& testList = TestCollector::GetTestList();
        if (0==testList.count(pTestName)) {
            testList.insert(std::make_pair(pTestName, std::make_shared<T>()));
        }
    }
};
}

#define ADD_TEST(className) static TestCollector::UnitTestClass<className> \
    test(#className);

#endif // TESTCOLLECTOR_H
```

Then, just add the ADD_TEST(class) line in your test header like this:

```
#ifndef TESTRANDOMENGINES_H
#define TESTRANDOMENGINES_H

#include <QtTest>
#include "TestCollector.h"

class TestRandomEngines : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private Q_SLOTS:
    void test1();
};

ADD_TEST(TestRandomEngines)

#endif // TESTRANDOMENGINES_H
```

And and to run all the tests, just do:

```
#include "TestCollector.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    auto nFailedTests = TestCollector::RunAllTests(argc, argv);
    std::cout << "Total number of failed tests: "
              << nFailedTests << std::endl;
    return nFailedTests;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the following code to collect all test results:

```
#include "testclassa.h"
#include "testclassb.h"
#include <QtTest>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    int failedTests = 0;
    TestClassA testClassA
    TestClassB testClassB
    failedTests += QTest::qExec(&testClassA, argc, argv);
    failedTests += QTest::qExec(&testClassB, argc, argv);

    if(failedTests > 0){
        qDebug() << "total number of failed tests: " << failedTests;
    }else{
        qDebug() << "all tests passed :)";
    }
    return failedTests;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Build with CMake and not QMake, and add two test targets.

```
add_executable(firstTest tst_testfirst.cpp)
add_test(NAME firstTest COMMAND firstTest)

add_executable(secondTest tst_testsecond.cpp)
add_test(NAME secondTest COMMAND secondTest)
```

Both tst_testfirst.cpp and tst_testsecond.cpp have their own QTEST_MAIN lines.

Qt Creator will run both test classes. If you're running them from the command line, you run the tests with "ctest".

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it:

- Create a general "subdirs" project.
- Put the code under test in a C++ library subproject.
- Instead of using a unit test project, I use a console application subproject.
- Link the library to this console application, don't forget to handle the dependencies in the .pro file at the top of the hierarchy.
- In this console subproject, define as many test classes as you wish, and launch them in the main of this same project.

I basically made a slight variation of [this post](https://sites.google.com/a/embeddedlab.org/community/technical-articles/qt/qt-posts/creatingandexecutingasingletestprojectwithmultipleunittests).