# How to run multiple tests in Qt without calling QTest::qExec multiple times?

Tags: c++, qt, qtestlib

I have a project with multiple independent libraries, and for each library I wish to create it's own test suite. I plan to have a single executable that links all suites, and to be able to run either all tests or a single test from the Qt Creator *Test* window. How to do that?

The basic Qt tutorial considers only the case where a single test object is being created, and one of the macros `QTEST_MAIN`, `QTEST_APPLESS_MAIN` or `QTEST_GUILESS_MAIN` is used.

There are advices like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12207504/11218687) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987301/how-to-run-multiple-qtest-classes) where the `main` function is created manually and the `QTest::qExec` function is called multiple times. This solution doesn't work anymore (or at least I failed to solve my problem in this way), as the `QTest::qExec` function [shall not be called more than once](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest.html#qExec):

> For stand-alone test applications, this function should not be called
> more than once, as command-line options for logging test output to
> files and executing individual test functions will not behave
> correctly.

How to use several test objects in a single executable? What are the idiomatic/recommended ways to develop tests in Qt where the tests cannot share the same object with a single `initTestCase`/`cleanupTestCase` pair?

I'm using Qt 5.14.0 with Qt Creator 4.11.0 + QMake. The OS is Windows.

**Note!** I've already asked this question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67379122/how-to-run-multiple-tests-in-qt-without-calling-qtestqexec-multiple-times), but it was mistakenly closed as duplicated with [How to run multiple QTest classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987301/how-to-run-multiple-qtest-classes). Pay special attention to that my question is slightly different, and the solution that was provided to the other question doesn't work anymore (however it could have worked in 2016). The crucial part of my question is how to achieve the goal without calling the `QTest::qExec` function multiple times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run multiple QTest classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987301/how-to-run-multiple-qtest-classes)  It has code to aggregate the test functions in an answer.  The example calls `qExec()` multiple times, but you can also code an aggregate test class.  It is not a different question, you just want a different answer.  You can answer that question with an aggregate test class.

Comment: @artlessnoise, please read my question again: I'm explicitly referencing that answer as not relevant one.