# Where exactly do I put QTEST_MAIN?

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing

I wanted to add some unit tests to an existent Qt application, but I can't figure out how to do it.

The official documentation [explains it](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qttestlib-tutorial1-example.html), telling that I need to create a class containing the test code (I suppose that both the class itself and its implementation belong to the same file?) Then, the documentation states:

> Finally, to make our test case a stand-alone executable, the following two lines are needed:
>
> ```
> QTEST_MAIN(TestQString)
> #include "testqstring.moc"
> ```

Do I have to add it in the same file which contains the test code? Or do I have to create some other file? Or maybe I am supposed to put it in the exising `main.cpp`?

[Another official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtest-overview.html) seems even more cryptic regarding `QTEST_MAIN`:

> Finally, if the test class has a static public void initMain() method, it is called by the QTEST_MAIN macros before the QApplication object is instantiated. This was added in 5.14.

In their example, however, there is no `initMain` method. Do I need to add one? And, anyway, what should I do with the actual `QTEST_MAIN` macro?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like:

1. `QTEST_MAIN` replaces the `main` function. Essentially, the answer to my original question is to throw the existing `main` and put `QTEST_MAIN` instead. It compiles and, when ran, executes the tests.
2. It runs only a single class (!), and “the proper way is to have [one] test project per test class.” (!) ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987301/how-to-run-multiple-qtest-classes#comment67576903_37987301))
3. There is a `QTest::qExec` function that can be called instead of using `QTEST_MAIN`—one can call it from within an existing `main`. However, one call is still matching one test class, and the function “shall not be called more than once.” ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67405702/240613))

A more “standard” way of doing tests would be, therefore, to move to a more mature testing framework, such as GTest. What I didn't know is that including Qt in a GTest project is very easy. One has to add:

```
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets)
```

and:

```
target_link_libraries(... Qt6::Core Qt6::Gui Qt6::Widgets)
```

to `CMakeLists.txt`, and that's pretty much all that's needed.